# How to write a 'where' query in hibernate using criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Let me consider one simple sql query

```
select username from tbl_customer where username="user" and password="12345";
```

How can i write this query in hibernate using criteria

Thanks. Hoping for positive response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to create the Criteria object, then you need to pass the where clause condition to the criteria object as well you have to set the projection property for selecting particular column data.

By seeing your SQL query,

```
select username from tbl_customer where username="user" and password="12345";
```

I believe you want to fetch the particular column `username` from the table `tbl_customer`. This can be done using `Projections`. You have to set the projection property for which column data you want.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class)
  criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("username"));
  criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("username", user),Restrictions.eq("password", 12345))
);
List<String> userNames = criteria.list();
```

This will return only the username column data from that table.

Comment: @NishanDhungana  I've edited the answer as you updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class) 
.add(Restrictions.eq("username", 
"user").add(Restrictions.eq("password","12345"));
```

Please note that, I do consider entity name as `Customer` for `tbl_customer` and you created session correctly.